# How to hide a cell value, and only show its value when a cell is selected in Excel?

Tags: excel

I want to make an excel file to manage my passwords, but I don't want every single password to be visible when I only need to see one and I don't wanna make multiple sheets just for 2 cells of data in each sheet. It's something like this:

[Passord hidden when the cell is not selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIuBB.png)

[Password shown when the cell is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGACF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have a cell, for example A2, for each password that you select Hide/Show. Data validation works here.

Then an if() like so:

```
=if(A2="Hide","","Password")
```

Enter the if() in B2 and put the real password in place of "password".

So you can use A2 for all the passwords or do this for each.

Comment: Well it works but not what I have in mind though, and I can see the password in the formula bar without selecting Show/Hide